# Is user actions flow can be tracked with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

a website have some sections/sub-pages, basically, user can choose a path to explore site, it can be a couple possibilites like;

- homepage -> gallery -> registration -> voting page -> posting an entry
- a sub page(from another website) -> registration -> gallery -> votingpage
- gallery -> registration -> gallery
- a subpage -> gallery -> voting pages

So What I would like to track is finding out most used user browsing flows. 
Is that can be track with google analytics ? Is there a function or method for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default report called *User Flows*. Look for it under Audience. From [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1709395?hl=en), "This will give you a graphical representation of the paths users took through your site, from the source, through the various pages, and where along their paths they exited your site".

Alternatively, you could look at using [Content Groups](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167), which based on your possibilities, would allow you to group a broad number of pages under a group, and then you'd have the ability to look at the "path" they took to get from content group to content group.